# docker compose nginx reverse proxy mount config

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

I'm trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy using the below docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - "nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - nginxtest
  nginxtest:
    image: nginx
volumes:
  nginx-conf:
```

Inside `${PWD}/nginx-conf` I've the `default.conf` file like so

```
http {
  server {
    listen          80;
    location / {
      proxy_pass      http://nginxtext;
    }
  }
}
```

`nginx` container doesn't load my reverse proxy config; instead it loads default config.

Comment: Are you trying to use bind mount volume, some folder named `nginx-conf` to be mapped to `/etc/nginx/conf.d`, or you are using named volume with name `nginx-conf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to achieve, as per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).
Those lines are of interest in this particular case:

```
 # Path on the host, relative to the Compose file
  - ./volume_name:/some/docker/path

  # Named volume
  - volume_name:/some/docker/path
```

If you are trying to mount folder from host, to nginx configuration folder, update the *volumes* part to the following:

```
volumes:
  - "~/nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d"
```